# Vista: Alt + Shift + P opens Windows Media Player; how to delete this hotkey?

Tags: windows-vista, hotkeys

I just bought a new laptop, and am having to learn Vista. (My desktop has XP.)

I was just trying to set some shortcut keys, and wanted to use  Alt + Shift + P for Anywho.com, but to my surprise  Alt + Shift + P  is already taken. It calls Windows Media Player. Now I like WMP and will use it a lot, but I want my Alt + Shift + P for AnyWho.com.

BTW I have PC Magazine's Hotkey Detective 2 (http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,5082,00.asp), but it doesn't show that  Alt + Shift + P  is taken.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a documented behavior of Vista. However, this **is** a documented behavior of Windows Media Player itself: 
ALT+SHIFT+P means `Restore the Player from mini Player mode`.

This Microsoft [article](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/howto/mini_full_how_to.aspx) defines mini Player mode as:

> When you use the mini Player, the
>   Player minimizes to the Windows
>   taskbar, but you can still access
>   playback controls and view
>   visualizations and information about
>   the currently playing item.

In mini player mode the minimized Media Player looks like this:

[image: image1]

You can turn off this mode by right clicking on the taskbar, pointing to Toolbars, and then **unchecking** Windows Media Player.

[image: image2]

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. But is it the case that my Alt + Shift + P cannot be made available for any other purpose?

Comment: Yes, if you turn mini-mode off. If you leave it on, then yes when WMP is not running and doesn't establish its keyboard hook. (I believe so, but never tried it.)

Comment: Excellent--this works as advertised!

Answer (score 1):

Find the icon/shortcut for Windows Media Player, right click on it and do properties and look for "Shortcut Key"

Delete it!

[image]

It is also possible (if the above doesn't work) that you have "hotkey" buttons on your laptop that are hard mapped to certain combos such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and then you have to use the hotkey manager program to change what pressing that button does.

Comment: A thorough search found 3 shortcuts for WMP; however, none have a shortcut key assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the hotkey with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
!+p::Run http://www.anywho.com/
```